# Can you do a paired t test in online calculator using only mean and SD?

Tags: t-test, p-value, paired-data

I have only the MEAN And SD no data

Answer (score 3):

If you have the mean and sd of each group separately then you cannot do it.

If you have the mean and sd of the differences and the number of pairs, and are willing to make the necessary assumptions, you can do it, since the formula for the paired t-test is

$ t = \frac{\bar{d}}{\sqrt{s^2/n}} $

where the numerator is the average difference, s^2 is the variance and n is number of pairs.

Answer (score 1):

**Paired** $t$-test, as the name suggests, [quoting Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test#Paired_samples),

> typically consist of a sample of matched pairs of similar units, or
>   one group of units that has been tested twice (a "repeated measures"
>   t-test).

so to conduct it you need pairs of observations from two groups. You need them because you compare the differences between cases in each pair, so to compute mean and standard deviation of the differences. If you have only means and standard deviations of two groups this is not enough.

Comment: You don't need the pairs if you have the mean of the differences and the sd of the differences.

Comment: @Glen_b right, the wording was misleading, thanks.